# What is the Tzitz atoning for?

Tags: kohen-gadol, bigdei-kehunah, maseches-zevachim

In [Zevachim 88b](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.88b.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A5%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D) it details that the unique clothing of the kohen gadol atoned for different categories of sin. By the tzitz it says:

> וציץ מכפר על עזות פנים "And the frontplate of the High Priest atones
> for brazenness."

What exactly is עזות? Where can I find more information about this atonement of the tzitz?

Comment: Have a look at Malbim's fantastic essay in Tetzaveh. He ties each garment to different elements of the psyche.

Comment: @Shalom do you have a direct link for that? I would love to learn it.

Comment: See also 
Rabbeinu Bahya
, Shemot 28:4

Comment: See also [this sefer, starting from כיצד הבגדים מכפרים](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/626324/p/38/t/0.363101079350404141234/fs/ZZukps9PcFPt9GzXpDNABiDGddsfuYsP6Y6qVcfclwoG/start/6140/end/6200/c)

Comment: [This Torah Teminah](https://www.sefaria.org/Torah_Temimah_on_Torah%2C_Exodus.29.1.2?vhe=Torah_Temimah,_Vilna,_1904&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A5%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%A2%D7%9C%20%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%A4%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D) might also be interesting; answering your question.